# How to send TextBox value from modal window to main window programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to learn WPF MVVM I would need to understand how to update a textbox value via a modal window. Below the code, I wrote passes the value to the viewmodel but does not update the textbox. Thanks in advance

**UserControl** con il TextBox

```
<TextBox x:Name="Text01UC" Text="{Binding TextUC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" Height="33"/>
```

**UserControl Behind**

```
 namespace InvioDati
{
 public partial class textbox : UserControl
{
public textbox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var vm = new ModelTextView();
    this.DataContext = vm;
    vm.Load();
}

private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MoadalWindow md = new MoadalWindow();
    md.ShowDialog();
}
}
}
```

**ModelTextView**

```
namespace InvioDati
 {
  class ModelTextView : BaseViewModel
   {
    private ModelText dati = new ModelText();
    public string TextUC
    {
        get => dati.TextVal;
        set
        {
            dati.TextVal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Load() { 
    TextUC = "GoodMorning";

    }
    public void Ricevi(string valore)
    {
        TextUC = valore;

    }
 }
}
```

**ModalWindow Code behind**
    namespace InvioDati
    {

```
public partial class MoadalWindow : Window
{
    public MoadalWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ModelTextView nd = new ModelTextView();
        nd.Ricevi(Send.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The simple way to have them both update is to have them both be the same ViewModel. Is there a reason you are pasing the value via a method? Why not instantiate both views with a shared data context reference?

Comment: That's lot of code my friend. Remove `BaseViewModel` and extra white lines, compress your code so that readers can focus more on your problem. Also make sure you post relevant code only, not everything that participates in MVVM flow.

Comment: `MoadalWindow` creates `ModelTextView` locally in the `Test_Click` and then get destroyed past that. You need to pass that back to the `MainWindow`'s `textbox`'s `DataContext`.

Comment: Meanwhile, thanks for the answers, I entered the code to show the problem well. Practically by pressing the button in the modal the value reaches the variable but the textbox does not update

Comment: I have reduced the code, in practice from the ModalWindow the value passes and the variable is updated but the textbox is not updated. The datacontex is already instantiated. I used a method to do some tests I do not know how else to call a modal window

Comment: kurakura88 : I do not understand what you mean. The datacontex is already instantiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` of the `ModalWindow` to the same instance of `ModelTextView` in `textbox.xaml.cs`:

```
private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MoadalWindow md = new MoadalWindow();
    md.DataContext = this.DataContext;
    md.ShowDialog();
 }
```

You can then either bind directly to the `TextUC` property or do the following in `ModalWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ModelTextView nd = DataContext as ModelTextView;
    nd.Ricevi(Send.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Great friend your solution works, you could explain the approach to me

Comment: @Alm: You are creating a new instance of the ModelTextView in your code. You should call the Ricevi of the already existing instance as the TextBox is bound to the TextUC property of this instance.

Comment: Although this works your ViewModel should be written so that it works regardless of it being a new instantiation or not.  This fixes your immediate problem due to the way you've designed it but if you want to truly learn MVVM then fixing it this way should be temporary.

Comment: @Michael Puckett II Thanks, as you would do it correctly. I'll shortly describe the thing, I have a textbox and at the click of the button I would like to open a modal with a listview in order to select the options

Answer (score 0):

1. You must use a mediator in order not to break mvvm here.
   Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern#C#

1b. Add Observer pattern to create notifications for value changes.

2. Dialogs are evil within MVVM, usually you won't need them. What you want is an overlaying View, which can be Data bound in any way as there is no break in the visual tree
3. If you want to use "dialogs", implement a DialogService to do so.

Edit: here is a draft on how you create something "popup" like in the most simple way:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <!--Invert visability of all controls below via binding-->
        <YourMainControl/>
        <Rect Fill="Black" Opacity=".5 Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <YourSubControl Visibility="Hidden"/> 
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I'm very interested in what you say .. I used a dialog because I could not think of anything else .. For what I need even a popup near the button can be fine. What would you do instead of the Modal?

Comment: I added a draft sample to my answer... Of course you can use something like ContentControls oder whatever Control Trees you like. This is the most simple way, if you want to use Just one VM oder a Simple Tree of VM with direct references.